# What's the difference between criticise and reprimand, are they synonymous?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm and ESL teacher and the word reprimand came up in the lesson. I asked the student to define "reprimand" and he said it means to criticise someone. I don't feel that the words are synonymous. For the life of me, I cannot find any information on this. Can someone assist?

Comment: Where did you look for information? What did a dictionary or two tell you? Please show your research so the community doesn't repeat it.

Comment: No, they are not synonymous. To _reprimand_ someone is to give them a 'telling-off' - to speak to them sternly about something they have done wrong. To _criticise_  is to draw attention to a fault or mistake. It could be done angrily, or it could be done kindly and meant to help.

Comment: A reprimand comes from a person of authority, power, or responsibility. A teacher may reprimand a student, but a student cannot really reprimand a teacher. _To criticize/criticise_ is more democratic. Everybody can criticize anyone or anything they want.

Comment: Enter reprimand in Google.  You will get a list of sources; click on any link that offers a definition of reprimand.  For example, you will find this [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reprimand) link that defines reprimand.  Now do the same for criticize.  If the difference between the two is still unclear, edit your question to explain what you do not understand.  Or, do you not have Google?

Comment: @ab2 obviously I did do research. A dictionary is my first point of reference in a matter like this. There is no need to be patronising. If you don't want to assist, don't answer.

Comment: @Kyle Mostert I didn't mean to be patronizing.  But I am genuinely puzzled as to why looking up the words in a dictionary did not solve your problem.  This site gets quite a few questions similar to yours, that many of us think a look-up would solve.  It would be helpful if you explained why the dictionaries did not at least partially solve your problem.  And, consider what your reply would have been to one of your students who asked a question such as yours:  wouldn't you have started with a tutorial on how he should start finding the answer on his own?  As for obviously, it was not obvious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'Reprimand' implies a certain degree of authority.  Only a person with authority over someone else may reprimand them. A reprimand usually comes with some kind of consequence,  although it may be a 'warning'.

On the other hand anyone may criticize someone else.

So a boss may reprimand subordinate, but a subordinate (or an equal) may only criticize his boss.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I appreciate the time and effort you went to.

Comment: Downvote on an already accepted answer? Maybe an explanation is called for.